# IllegalAccessError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/reflect/opt/Const

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I am getting this exception when calling a webservice that I am implementing:

```
10:37:52,908 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webservices.jaxws.servlet.http] (http-/10.32.160.201:8081-1) caught throwable: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/reflect/opt/Const
    at my.package.service.jaxws.MyWsType$JaxbAccessorF_mywstypefield.set(FieldAccessor_Integer.java:59)
    at ...
```

I am calling it with SoapUI.

Answer (score 2):

The request I was using was sending a '?' as value to that field:

```
<MyWsType>
  <mywstypefield>?<mywstypefield>
  ...
```

And instead of giving an informative '? is not a valid value' or at least a NumberFormatException, I was receiving the IllegalAccessError. 
So I am registering this question and answer here, may it help someone.